# packet creation in ruby

Tags: ruby, hex, serial-port

I'm trying to create a packet to send over serial using ruby-serialport. This seems like it should be simple, and it works when I just write a string:

```
packet = "\xFF\x03\x10\x01\x01\xFE"
sp.write(packet)
=>hardware does what it's supposed to, opens the door represented by the 4th hex value
```

but I obviously need to do it programmatically, and I can't figure out the right way. Here are just a few of the things I've tried:

```
door = 1    
packet = "\xFF\x03\x10" + door.to_s(16) + "\x01\xFE"
sp.write(packet)
=> can't convert fixnum into string
```

and

```
door = 1
packet = "\xFF\x03\x10" + door.to_a.pack('H*') + "\x01\xFE"
sp.write(packet)
=> to_a will be obsolete
can't convert fixnum into string
```

and

```
door = 1
sp.write("\xFF\x03\x10")
sp.write(door)
sp.write("\x01\xFE")
=>no response from hardware
```

Can anyone help me out on how to properly convert a number into the right hex notation for serialport and joining to the other hex strings? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're really going to get into trouble if you insist on using strings to represent otherwise binary data. What you really need is `pack`:

```
packet = [ 0xFF, 0x30, 0x10, door, 0x01, 0xFE ].pack('C*')
```

This makes it very easy to construct and deconstruct arbitrary binary data. The method supports not just unsigned characters but a variety of other types that are commonly used.

You may even want to construct your own method to read and write this:

```
def write_packet(*bytes)
  sp.write(bytes.flatten.pack('C*'))
end
```

Comment: Right, it makes a lot of sense, and that's what I'm doing on the receiving end, I guess I was just being lazy (and very inexperienced working at this low level) on the writing end because the thing I'm interfacing with has two commands that need one variable each. But might just as well do it right, thank you very much for the advice.

Comment: Keep in mind that under Ruby 1.9 using `chr` you may run into conflict with UTF-8 or your default character set. Ensure that your file-handles are open in `BINARY` mode or you may find characters getting converted on you and the data-stream will be mangled. Ruby 1.8 is living in the "Ignorance is Bliss" world of character encoding. I get an `Encoding::CompatibilityError` error for `door` values > 127 when using `chr`. `pack` is the only sane way to deal with this.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
door = 1    
packet = "\xFF\x03\x10" + door.chr + "\x01\xFE"
```

Comment: oh, fantastic, thank you! I feel stupid for not looking more carefully at integer methods. Really appreciate it.

Comment: This won't work in Ruby 1.9 using UTF-8 encoding for values of `door` over 127.